# Windows phone 8 Emulator not launching from task-bar

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

The emulator of windows phone 8 not launching from the task-bar. I can see its working normally in small screen preview in task bar. I don't know what is the reason for this problem.There is no error code is showing.

Any ideas on how to get it up and running?

Comment: Does it launch when you run/debug your project from Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: its launching to task-bar only.i can show my project running in small screen preview in task-bar. But its not open from task-bar.

Comment: Have you tried a repair/re-install of the WP8 SDK?

Comment: No.How to reinstall or repair the sdk?

Comment: go to Programs and Features, select Windows Phone 8 SDK from the list, click on Change, then click Repair.

Answer (score -1):

Check the IP address of your Emulator